# Illegal instruction with openssl on Android arm64

Tags: openssl, android-ndk

I'm trying to build libcurl with openssl for Android. I'm building on Windows, but I use MSYS2 for building openssl and libcurl. Whenever I run my program, I hit SIGILL. I'm assuming I'm building openssl incorrectly somehow, as the error occurs before hitting any of my code, but I'm not sure.

This is how I build openssl. I have version 1.1.1k

```
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/f/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570
PATH=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin:$PATH
./Configure android-arm64 -D__ANDROID_API__=23
make
```

Here is the stack.

```
_armv8_sha512_probe 0x000000766a0d2cf0
OPENSSL_cpuid_setup 0x000000766a17e734
__dl__ZL10call_arrayIPFviPPcS1_EEvPKcPT_mbS5_ 0x000000775c43abdc
__dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv 0x000000775c43adf8
__dl__Z9do_dlopenPKciPK17android_dlextinfoPKv 0x000000775c426968
__dl___loader_android_dlopen_ext 0x000000775c4220e0
android_dlopen_ext 0x00000077591490bc
OpenNativeLibraryInNamespace 0x0000007756d54fa8
OpenNativeLibrary 0x0000007756d54c80
art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, _jobject*, _jclass*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) 0x00000076d5fbdb9c
JVM_NativeLoad 0x00000076cbf1c0ec
art_jni_trampoline 0x0000000070464af8
art_quick_invoke_static_stub 0x00000076d5d7e5bc
art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*) 0x00000076d5d8d08c
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f26468
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f2140c
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2ec10
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2ec10
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2e684
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2ec10
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2ec10
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2e684
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6e74
art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5efcb64
bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) 0x00000076d5f213f0
void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) 0x00000076d5f2fed0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x00000076d5d89bdc
MterpInvokeStatic 0x00000076d61d4eb0
mterp_op_invoke_static 0x00000076d5d78998
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3356592462228958834) 0x00000076d5ef6d78
artQuickToInterpreterBridge 0x00000076d61c2ee8
art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge 0x00000076d5d8744c
art_quick_instrumentation_entry 0x00000076d5d87640
```

I'm not totally sure how to debug from here, so any help is appreciated.

**Update 1**
I forgot to mention that I'm currently hitting this issue with a Google Pixel 4 on Android version 10.

Comment: `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup` (armcap.c) is calling various functions in arm64cpuid.S to check for supported features. It is supposed to catch any SIGILLs by installing a signal handler, but apparently that is not working in this case. On which specific device and Android version are you testing?

Comment: I added information in the post including the device and Android version that I'm hitting the issue on.